# Multiple CLLocationManagers have more than 20 monitored regions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, geofencing

I'm using 2 location managers for my app to monitor different type of regions(CLBeaconRegion & CLCircularRegion). I read about the 20 limited for monitored regions. When I tried debugging I noticed that my monitoredRegion property has more than 20 regions. Does this mean the limit of 20 apply to each location manager, but they all share the same monitoredRegion property( if theres 2 locations managers used the limit is 20+20 = 40)?

For example, if manager A monitors 9 CLBeaconRegions and manager B monitors 20 CLCircularRegions, each of the monitor's monitoredRegion property would be 29.

Comment: Have you tested to see if they all get callbacks?  I would doubt it.

Comment: @davidgyoung I haven't tested them all for callbacks, but when I tried adding 300 CLCircularRegions to monitoredRegion, only 20 was added.

Answer (score 1):

Monitored regions is a shared resource, which means that every single instance of `CLLocationManager` you create actually operates on the very same list of monitored regions.

You can check that by creating CLLocationManager "A", start monitoring for a region with it. Then create a CLLocationManager "B", and print its `monitoredRegions` property. You'll see the region you started monitoring for, even though it was a different CLLocationManager that registered it with iOS.

It is this shared list that's subject to the 20-region limit, which means it's not possible to bypass the limit by creating more CLLocationManagers.

*[How and why your `monitoredRegions` have more than 20 entries is an interesting thing though. I wasn't able to replicate that.]*